# Copy information from one worksheet to another when a cell within that row meets certain criteria

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet which keeps track of all employees that are on workman's comp/disability. It keeps track of information like when they were injured, when their last doctor's visit was, etc.

Once they have not submitted a doctor's note within 4 weeks, I send out a letter requesting one. I currently have it set up where the cells turn red when it has been over 4 weeks since the last note so I can go through and find who I need to send a note to.

I would like to take this to the next step, and have their information automatically populate into another worksheet once it has been over 4 weeks so I can simply mail merge from Sheet 2.

Here is my setup:
Sheet 1:
  Row 1 'Header Row'.
  Rows 2 and down 'Each employee and all their records'.
  Column A 'Last Name'.
  Column B 'First Name'.
  Column C 'Street Address'.
  Column D 'City, State, Zip'.
  Column K 'Injury'.
  Column Z 'Last Doctor's Visit'.
  Column AA 'Today's Date'.
  Column AB 'Days Since Last Doctor's Visit (calculated by formula subtracting    Column Z from Column AA).
  Column AC 'Letter Sent'.

If AB is greater than 28, I would like the information in each of these columns to be copied to Sheet 2, columns A-I.

Then (if possible) when I type a date in column I, Sheet 2 (Letter Sent), I would like for that entire line to be removed from Sheet 2, and the data in column I, Sheet 2 to be entered in column AC, Sheet 1.

Any help you can give would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA answer or without any code?

Comment: I am open to any answer that will get done what I need to do. Not very familiar with VBA, but I can figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to copy columns A through I from sheet1 to the next open row, columns A through I on sheet2 if AB is greater than 28. If this is correct, the below will do that.

```
Sub Loop_For_Erin()
Dim c as Range
For Each c in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB1:AB" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
   If c.value > 28 Then
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & c.row & ":I" & c.row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row)
   End If
Next C
```

Comment: It's actually columns A-D, K and Z-AC on Sheet 1 to be copied to the next open row in columns A-I on Sheet 2 if AB is greater than 28.             Then (if possible) once a value is entered in column I Sheet 2, the entire row be deleted from Sheet 2, and that value to be entered in column AC.

Comment: Copying those columns will not be difficult. I am not sure I understand the second portion of what you are trying to do. Can you please explain that further?

Comment: I am going to use Sheet2 as a list of employees who need a letter sent out. Once I send them a letter, I no longer want them to appear on Sheet2. Instead, I want the date I sent the letter to appear on Sheet1 column AC.

Comment: It may be too difficult to get that portion to work. Maybe instead of doing that, we could just add that if there is a value in Sheet1, column AC, the line would NOT copy onto Sheet2 even if AB>28???